# how can we set two value in input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can we set two value in input in react in my below i m trying to do set in value two parameter in input but i am trying to do that i m not able to set

This is my input type

```
                     <input      
                        value={type.id}
                        type="radio"
                        name="select"
                        key={j}
                        onChange={(e) =>
                          this.setState({ selectedId: e.target.value })
                        }
                      />
```

and i want to set in here  value={type.id, type.rollno }.

how can we do that

anybody help me out this.

in my code right now in console i m getting only id when i click row in table but i want to getting in console id and rollno both

how can we do that. anyone help me out. its very thankful

Comment: anyone help me out this??

Comment: simply add ```value={`${type.id}  ${type.rollno}`}```

Comment: @kunalpanchal thanks and how can we set in  onChange={(e) =>
                          this.setState({ selectedId: e.target.value })
                        }   in one change selecetid and selectedrolno??

Comment: value={`${type.id}  ${type.rollno}`} its not work actually can u show m somtng in here in my code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-s58do?file=/index.js:2216-2534

Comment: its very helpful for me i m stuck on that https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-s58do?file=/index.js:2216-2534 in my code right now i m getting only id in console when i click on row but i want id and rollno both

Comment: what out put do you expect and what input are you giving please could you explain in details ?

Comment: @kunalpanchal can u open my this code https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-s58do?file=/index.js so when i click row then in console i am getting data like id and rollno on the basis of row select   this is fine but i m not able to open url link.

Comment: the urls worked fine for me, I mean they opened on the new tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232081/discussion-between-kunal-panchal-and-rennu-kumari).

Comment: ok and console what u geeting ??when click row??

Comment: @kunalpanchal can u update this??

Comment: i have updated this below please check the answer

Comment: @kunalpanchal  thanks for help and support

Comment: no worries @rennu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed your code just need a lil update on switch condition you use the code below:

```js
switch (this.state.selectedId.split(" ")[0]) {
  case "1":
    window.open("https://bing.com", "_blank");
    break;
  case "2":
    window.open("https://google.com", "_blank");
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Explanation:

as you are adding both the values to the input here

```
 <input value={`${state.id} ${state.roll}`} />
```

onChange Event is updating the new state which is somewhat like this:

```
  this.state.selectedId = "1 8";
```

you need to split the value and use the first one which is the ID from the `this.state.selectedId`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input value={`${state.id} ${state.roll}`} />
```

```
 onChange={e => setState({
      ...state,
      selectedId: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

Comment: ok thanks @miraj and how can we set in onChange={(e) => this.setState({ selectedId: e.target.value }) } in one change selecetid and selectedrolno??

Comment: <input value={`${state.id} ${state.roll}`} />  its not worked

Comment: watch the backtik `\``